# Why is the SSL configuration for Artifactory not working?

Tags: ssl, artifactory

I am trying to configure Artifactory to work with SSL, the problem is that with some of the keystores he is starting up, but the web UI does not connect (I mean- if you want to open https://:8443), it will not show the welcome screen),  how can it be debugged to see what is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to debug it, but the problem was resolved, I did not specify the correct value of the keystore alias

Comment: what do you mean by the correct value of Keystore alias?

Comment: I wrote a parameter of the keystore alias- with wrong value